# How do I get data from json and show it in html

Tags: html, json

I am a beginner and there is a question I would like to ask everyone

For example, my URL to get JSON is:

The returned JSON is:

```
{
"Data":{
"id": 1312,
"Name": "Steem Dollars",
"Symbol": "SBD",
"website_slug": "steem-dollars",
"Level": 313,
"circulating_supply": 15185862.0,
"total_supply": 15185862.0,
"max_supply":null,
Quotes: {
"Dollar": {
"Price": 1.2369,
"volume_24h": 660195.0,
"market_cap": 18783392.0,
"percent_change_1h": 0.84,
"percent_change_24h": - 5.87,
"percent_change_7d": -10.61
}
},
"last_updated": 1529462954
},
"Metadata":{
"time stamp": 1529462906,
"Error": null
}
}
```

How do I get information in HTML through https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1312/ and display the following fields in the HTML:

- name
- symbol
- rank
- price
- Volume_24h
- Market_cap
- Percent_change_1h
- Percent_change_24h
- Percent_change_7d

Who can give an example, Thanks again.

Comment: this is just a piece of the puzzle that is development.  You will need to understand some HTML and how to link Javascript to HTML.

Comment: You should learn Javascript, Ajax and HTML for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) so you don't have to rely on other libraries, you can do something like.

You also need to know how an object works in JavaScript.

```js
function getElement(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

fetch('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1312/')
.then(res => res.json())
.then((res) => {
  const data = res.data;
  getElement('name').innerHTML =  'Name: ' + data.name;
  getElement('symbol').innerHTML = 'Symbol: ' + data.symbol;
  getElement('rank').innerHTML = 'Rank: ' + data.rank;
  getElement('price').innerHTML = 'Price: ' + data.quotes.USD.price;
  // do the rest here
});
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="name"></p>
  <p id="symbol"></p>
  <p id="rank"></p>
  <p id="price"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do I add ```getElement('price')``` according to the format. ```innerHTML = 'Price:' + data.price```, but the price field shows undefined

Comment: Because there is no price key inside the data object. price is inside the USD property of quotes property. You need to learn about objects.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript Way:

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = myObj.data.name;
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1312/", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

```html
<div id="name"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend jQuery for this. It handles JSON well.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 var url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1312/";
 $.getJSON( url, {
   format: "json"
 })
  .done(function( data ) {
     $("#iid").text(data.data.id);
     $("#name").text(data.data.name);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script></script>

<div id="iid"></div>
<div id="name"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON are basically in hierarchy structure. So in order to access specific attribute you need to go step by step.

You can use Jquery for ajax call.

So summing up your whole code looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1312/",                      
     function(json, status){

            var data = json.data;
            var quotes = data.quotes;
            var usd = quotes.USD;


            console.log(JSON.stringify(quotes));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data.name));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(quotes));

            $("#container").append(data.name+"<br>");

        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Get Data</button>

<div id="container" ></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution is to run on each key in the json file and set it to the same id name .

```
  $.getJSON( "resources/screenText.json", function( data ) {
      $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        $( `#${key}`).html(val);
      });
    });
```

see
[jQuery.getJSON()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

screenText.json :

```
{
  "one": "Singular sensation",
  "two": "Beady little eyes",
  "three": "Little birds pitch by my doorstep"
}
```

html:

```
<span id="one"></span>
<span id="two"></span>
<span id="three"></span>
```